# Does a Parallel way to extract unique elements from a DataFrame exists?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, duplicates

I have a HUGE database; and some of the lines are repeated. I could use the "unique()" function, but it takes like 5 minutes. Is there some way (maybe a parallel programming way) of doing the same?

Comment: You can use `kit::fduplicated` or `dplyr:distinct` Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800736/4157717 If you still require parallel computing, check out the `multidplyr` package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be faster, but you can use `distinct` from `dplyr` like:

`df %>% distinct(x)`

Another option is to use `group_by` (also from `dplyr`):

`df %>% group_by(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `data.table` package. Here's what you can do:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(x = 5000, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                 col2 = sample(x = 5000, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE))
dt <- copy(df)
setDT(dt) #here you convert a data.frame object into a data.table one by reference

unique(dt)
```

We can check a time gain using `microbenchmark` package:

```
microbenchmark(unique(df), unique(dt))

# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# unique(df) 1028.92260 1285.39321 1410.4072 1405.7486 1543.1486 1857.4901   100
# unique(dt)   83.11946   98.41596  148.0874  119.0889  155.0679  507.4944   100
```