# create column with union of ranges by group

Tags: r, list, group-by, data.table, range

I am trying to write code, preferably using `data.table`, to group data by `id` from a list column with ranges (`my_range`) into a new aggregate dataset with a column (`union_of_my_range`) containing the union of `my_range` for each id.

```
library(data.table)

#Input
d <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2),
                my_range=list(1:5,2:6,3:7,9:9)
                )

#Desired output:
g <- data.table(id=c(1,2),
                union_of_my_range=list(c(1:5,6),c(3:7,9))
                )
```

Preferably looking for a `data.table` solution,

This is what I have thus far:

```
d[, .(my_range_union = SOMETING unon my_range ) ,id]
```

but I am not able to keep track of all the lists interacting in the aggregation step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `union`

```
d[, .(my_range_union = list(Reduce(union, my_range))), id]
#   id my_range_union
#1:  1    1,2,3,4,5,6
#2:  2    3,4,5,6,7,9
```

Comment: thanks, This solution is faster than the solution above (18s vs 29s on a 1mm rows dataset)

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` `my_range` values, gather `unique` values and put it in a new list.

```
library(data.table)
d[, .(my_range_union = list(unique(unlist(my_range)))) ,id]

#   id my_range_union
#1:  1    1,2,3,4,5,6
#2:  2    3,4,5,6,7,9
```

Comment: This is great. The only problem is that unique is a bit of a slow function. A comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267510/how-to-speed-up-a-unique-dataframe-search) mentioned how 'distinct' is a faster replacement for deduplicating data.frames, but it did not work in this case.

Comment: `distinct` is in `dplyr` not `data.table`. The `unique` which I have used here is for vectors, `distinct` is for dataframes/tibbles and I don't think it applies here.